# How can I change the headings in the tooltwist page template so that I can include jquery-ui library?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, tooltwist

Whenever I am doing a deployment using tooltwist, I find that the header does not contain the jquery-ui library that I needed for my application.  How will I be able to insert it to the  part to make it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way and easiest way of doing this is to customize the page template for your tooltwist extension project, thus you will be deploying it inside your tooltwist project.

**To customize:**

1. Copy **page/** and **page_template/** folder under ttWbd/widgets/toolbox into your project's widget directory. (e.g. {projectName}_t/widgets/{projectName}_widgets/)
2. Open conf.xml of page_template and change the configuration appropriately for **linkedWidget**, **label** and **description** nodes. **linkedWidget** will have value like project **{projectName}_widgets.page**
3. If you already created pages on your project, you need to replace linkedWidget nodes of the configuration file (conf.xml) of all your pages from **toolbox.page** to **{projectName}_widget.page** including all version folders.
4. Under folder **page/** you can customize template header depend on the page mode you selected in your designer. For **mode = page** update **new_jquery_header.jsp**.

*Page Template:*

[image]

**NOTE:**
A new page template option will appear on your assets list when creating new assets.